# Localization : Which is a better approach of the following?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to implement localization in my existing project. I found out that i can use two ways to localize my project:

1. To take all alert messages and strings in **localizable.Strings** file and also by localizing my XIBs ( hence xibs get their own strings file for french or german language)
2. If i take all alert messages, image names , label texts, or HTML file names in localizable.strings file, i do not need to localize my XIBs anymore. So can i simply replace all text in localizable.strings file and forget about localizing the XIBs ?

Which is a better approach and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes option 2 is the right way of doing it.
If there are some sudden changes in UI, then you have to only add extra string to .string file rather than worrying about the UI changes.

Comment: But i have noticed that on developer.apple.com or any other tutorial , they have mostly used localizable.strings and also localized XIBs .. i.e the first option. Why is that so ?

Comment: You use localizable xibs when you want to change the xib behaviour, like, if you want to make a arabic that it is right to left writing, you would like to change the placing of some views. But mainly I have been working with the second approach.

Comment: Ok.. I will use the second approach then. Thanks